# iOS: Can a corrupt Core Data store be prevented or fixed?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, crash, corruption

I am building a camera app in Swift and am about to release a new version of it. Some users report that the app crashes on start and I also have had the same problem when removing old pictures in batches within that app.

Basically, when the store coordinator tries to save the database, it crashes. All normal operations, which in my case consist of adding and browsing pictures work fine but "larger changes to many objects" (deleting half the pictures or migrating the store to a newer version) lead to a crash. It is not the migration itself because it works on non-corrupt data.

My assumption is that during use, the old store got corrupted - why and how I can only speculate about. Maybe because the app had bugs or maybe because the users swiped the app away at the wrong moment. The app handles quite large sets of data and I had difficulties to save data at the correct moment. Too early and it affects the user interface, too late and the required information, i.e. from gps, is not there yet and I risk losing it or piling up unsaved data in memory that I cannot save quickly enough when the app terminates.

Here is the stacktrace for starting the new version, caused by a trivial store migration:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 0x17007db40
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000186e72c14 write + 8
1   libcopyfile.dylib               0x0000000186ce0d7c copyfile_internal + 1492
2   libcopyfile.dylib               0x0000000186ce35d4 copyfile + 4580
3   Foundation                      0x0000000188983910 -[NSFilesystemItemCopyOperation _handleFTSEntry:] + 428
4   Foundation                      0x0000000188982eb0 -[NSDirectoryTraversalOperation main] + 272
5   Foundation                      0x00000001888e50a4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 620
6   Foundation                      0x000000018897f728 -[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:options:error:] + 268
7   Foundation                      0x000000018897f928 -[NSFileManager copyItemAtURL:toURL:options:error:] + 416
8   CoreData                        0x000000018a2c6a90 +[NSSQLCore _replacePersistentStoreAtURL:destinationOptions:withPersistentStoreFromURL:sourceOptions:error:] + 768
9   CoreData                        0x000000018a2ad7f8 __182-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPrivateMathods) _replacePersistentStoreAtURL:destinationOptions:withPersistentStoreFromURL:sourceOptions:storeType:error:]_block_invoke + 480
10  CoreData                        0x000000018a2af3d8 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 168
11  CoreData                        0x000000018a29e890 _perform + 220
12  CoreData                        0x000000018a2ad524 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPrivateMathods) _replacePersistentStoreAtURL:destinationOptions:withPersistentStoreFromURL:sourceOptions:storeType:error:] + 256
13  CoreData                        0x000000018a307d74 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) _gatherDataAndPerformMigration:] + 2804
14  CoreData                        0x000000018a2a2f08 __91-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]_block_invoke + 4764
15  CoreData                        0x000000018a2af3d8 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 168
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000186d4a1bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000186d577f0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
18  CoreData                        0x000000018a29e87c _perform + 200
19  CoreData                        0x000000018a1b0470 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 388
20  KameraPROD                      0x00000001000e1244 specialized DataController.(persistentStoreCoordinator.getter).(closure #1) (DataController.swift:36)
21  KameraPROD                      0x00000001000e47dc AppDelegate.init() -> AppDelegate (DataController.swift:48)
22  UIKit                           0x000000018e0005a4 _UIApplicationMainPreparations + 1880
23  UIKit                           0x000000018dddc500 UIApplicationMain + 156
24  KameraPROD                      0x000000010006e160 main (AppDelegate.swift:5)
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000186d7d5b8 start + 4
```

iOS: 10.3 (14E5277a)
Xcode 8.3 beta 4
Hardware: iPhone 6s

This is the code for stack trace row 20:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

I am looking for:

1) a strategy to avoid this kind of corruption and
2) a way to fix it

Thankful for any insights
Andreas

Comment: Are you using any special options when creating your persistentStoreCoordinator like NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"synchronous": @"OFF"}? That could cause corruption.

Comment: *"My assumption is that during use, the old store got corrupted.."* That is an **extremely** big assumption to make.

Comment: Tom, can you explain why you state that? So far, ca. 95% of our users use the app without any problems and those large changes work just fine. The remaining cases are just as I described; read and append work flawless but large changes fail. I don't see why this would not fit the pattern of database corruption. What is your argument?

Comment: Jon, no we don't use any such options.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you have made a large assumption without any supporting evidence. The fact that the problem affects 5% of users does not indicate that data corruption is the cause. You're trying to fix a problem without knowing what's actually wrong. It **could** be corruption, but it's a **huge** assumption to jump to that conclusion.

Comment: Sure. I get that. I *know* it is an assumption and I know that it is possibly wrong. At least I have a theory and as long as I can't collect more information or ideas it will remain so. If I had the answer I would not post here asking for help. Your comments do not in any way add more information to the topic and I consider them patronizing.

Comment: do you have crash reports (of the said users who have the startup crash)?

Comment: Also your assumption about data corruption is probably wrong. Core data isn't corrupt by termination at the wrong moment so easily. More likely, if there is corruption, its related to improper migration or incorrect thread confinement of coreData objects/contexts